# Flutter Camerawesome package unable to record video on iOS, throwing image format not supported

Tags: ios, flutter, camera, image-formats

Implemented a basic camera with the camerawesome package from flutter. I am testing on an iPhone 7, iOS 14.3.
I am trying to record a simple video. When the method recordVideo from the videoController is called, the following error message appears.

```
The selected imageFormatGroup is not supported by iOS. Defaulting to brga8888

thread Orientation notifier being called after the activity is disposed #32, queue = 'camerawesome.dispatchqueue', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x10)
frame #0: 0x000000010045a834 camerawesome`-[VideoController newAudioSample:](self=0x00000002801d6890, _cmd="newAudioSample:", sampleBuffer=0x000000014be540e0) at VideoController.m:129:13
126 - (void)newAudioSample:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer {
127 if (_videoWriter.status != AVAssetWriterStatusWriting) {
128 if (_videoWriter.status == AVAssetWriterStatusFailed) {
-> 129 _videoRecordingEventSink([NSString stringWithFormat:@"writing video failed : %@", _videoWriter.error]);
^
130 }
131 return;
132 }
Target 0: (Runner) stopped.
Lost connection to device.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you are recording videos in `.mov` and its not supported by this package, or something like that. Try to record MP4 video

Comment: I am specifying the path to be .mp4, therefore I do not think that is the problem.